# how i can transport table in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: Table column structure]

This is my query:

```
select count(id) as Agendas, (select count(id) from publications) as Publication, (select count(id) from achievements) as Achievements from agenda_details
```

How can I take result in the following view?

```
| serial No|  Category     | Counts|
|     1    | Agendas       |   5   |
|     2    | Publications  |   5   |
|     3    | Achievements  |   5   |
```

Comment: Search for mysql unpivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a query like this:

```
select 1 as serial_No, 'Agendas' as Category, count(id) as Counts from agenda_details
union
select 2 as serial_No, 'Publications' as Category, count(id) as Counts from publications
union
select 3 as serial_No, 'Achievements ' as Category, count(id) as Counts from achievements
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this exactly what i need